Explicit formula for numbers defined recursively
Let's define the following coefficients in a recursive way (we suppose $p\le n$):
\begin{align*}
A_{n,p}(k) &=  w_{n,p}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{\min(n-1,p)} \frac1{2^{p+1-i}} \cdot A_{n-1,i}(k)   \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, for\,\,\,\, 1 \le k < n \\
A_{n,p}(n) &=  w_{n,p}\cdot \frac{1}{2^p}  
\end{align*}
with
\begin{align*}
w_{n,p} &= \begin{cases}  2 & \text{if $p=n$}\\  1 & \text{if $p<n$}  \end{cases}     
\end{align*}
(note: the ending criterion is implicitly defined by $A_{1,1}(1)=1$)
Question: is it possible to find an explicit formula (i.e. without recursion) for $A_{n,p}(k)$ ?
To me, it looks like counting how many times each power of $\frac1{2}$ appears in $A_{n,p}(k)$ and so it could probably be expressed as a sum of powers of $\frac1{2}$ weighted by some integer but I have not been successful in that direction so far.
On the other hand, there may exist some known methods to generically tackle such a problem  but I am not aware of any of them.
Here is a gp/pari code that implements the recursion:
coeff(n,p) = 
{
    local(res,tmp);

    res = vector(n,x,0);

    res[n] = 1;

    for (i=1, min(p,n-1),
        tmp = 2^(i-1)*coeff(n-1,i);
        for (k=1, n-1, res[k] += tmp[k]); 
    );

    return (res * if (n==p,2,1)/2^p);
}

and some numerical application:
? coeff(5,2)
%2 = [5/32, 5/32, 3/16, 1/4, 1/4]

